# Is it possible to debug when using ScriptBundle?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using the ScriptBundle class to include my javascript and style sheets for the performance enhancements that it provides. However, I have deployed to a different machine and am not sure what is wrong with the IIS configuration. I would like to turn on the debug briefly to get some information, but when I do that my javascript is broken (since nothing gets included) and my error is in a JSON call. So, is it possible to get any meaningful debug information while using ScriptBundle or are they mutually exclusive?

Comment: You can disable bundling and check what's wrong

Comment: Why would turning on debug break your javascript? In debug mode, nothing should get bundled or minified.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why the answer worked for you. Setting `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` should produce the same results of running in debug mode by causing bundling not to occur. If *not* bundling fixed your issue (which I assume since you accepted the answer which shows you how to force bundling to not occur), then your issue was occurring *because* you were still bundling in debug mode (otherwise it would've produced the same results)... which means you may still have a problem in production mode when you start bundling again.

Comment: When in debug mode, no javascript rendered.

Comment: @AnthonyPotts My point was the answer you accepted produces the same result simply from running in debug mode, which you were already doing. You haven't explained how simply turning off bundling fixed your problem (running in debug mode means bundling is turned off in almost all implementations).

Comment: What I am saying is that for whatever reason, which I can't speak to now, when I did this it worked and without it, it did not. If I understood why that worked there is a very good chance I would never have posed the question to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disassociate bundling from debug mode, you need to manually set the bundle optimization in your code. An easy way to do this is to add an `<appSetting>` to your web.config saying whether to optimize bundles or not then set [BundleTable.EnableOptimizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundletable.enableoptimizations(v=vs.110).aspx) accordingly:

**Web.config**

```
...
<appSettings>
    <add key="OptimizeBundles" value="false" />
</appSettings>
...
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    var optimizeBundles = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings['OptimizeBundles']);
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = optimizeBundles;
    ...
}
```